# for loop printing

Tags: python

In Pycharm this (for loop) code prints like this.

```
magicians = ['alice', 'david', 'carolina']
for magician in magicians:
       print(magician)
```

Output

```
alice,
david, 
carolina
```

I want it to print out like this.

```
alice

david

carolina
```

Does anyone know how or if pycharm can be edited to fix this issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Comment: This is not an IDE related issue. Why is Pycharm being brought up here? And why does your output contain comma?

Comment: This shouldn't have anything to do with pycharm, but I used pycharm and I cannot recreate your output. What are you doing to get this?

Comment: I'm flagging to close as the issue with the output cannot be recreated with the code provided. There's nothing in that code that should be causing commas to appear after alice and david.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm just starting and I'm following along with a book. I had the names like this. ['alice, 'david, 'caroline] Instead of this. ['alice', 'david', 'carloine'] pycharm is fine. I goofed up. Case closed. Thanks again for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pycharm doesn't seem to have anything to do with it.  It is in your print statement itself. You need to provide an extra newline character in the print statement.

There are several ways to append an additional newline character to the end of the `print()` statement.

`print(magician + '\n')`, `print(magician, '\n')` or even `print(magician, end='\n\n')`

But note, all of these will end up outputting

```
alice

david

carolina
          <- extra newline
```

If you want the exact output you requested (without the extra newline at the end) you would need something like

```
magicians = ['alice', 'david', 'carolina']

for i in range(len(magicians) -1):
   print(magicians[i], end='\n\n')
print(magicians[len(magicians) -1])
```

Comment: Welcome to the community.  If an answer has helped you solve your problem, you should accept it. See [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm just starting and I'm following along with a book. I had the names like this. ['alice, 'david, 'caroline] Instead of this. ['alice', 'david', 'carloine'] pycharm is fine. I goofed up. Case closed. Thanks again for helping.

Answer (score 0):

append new line (\n) at the end of print() as following code snippet:

```
magicians = ['alice', 'david', 'carolina']
for magician in magicians:
       print(magician + '\n')
```

**output:**

```
alice

david

carolina
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm just starting and I'm following along with a book. I had the names like this. ['alice, 'david, 'caroline] Instead of this. ['alice', 'david', 'carloine'] pycharm is fine. I goofed up. Case closed. Thanks again for helping.

Answer (score 0):

```
magicians = ['alice', 'david', 'carolina']
for magician in magicians:
    print(magician, end = '\n')
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm just starting and I'm following along with a book. I had the names like this. ['alice, 'david, 'caroline] Instead of this. ['alice', 'david', 'carloine'] pycharm is fine. I goofed up. Case closed. Thanks again for helping.